# Updating all Child object associated with parent record in Salesforce

Tags: architecture, salesforce, apex

I have a requirement where I need to update all the Child Object associated with parent object.

There are multiple option but I am trying to figure out the best option as more than 30 child objects needs to be updated.

Trigger(Most probably Will fail with CPU time limit exceed if not now but some where in future.)
Batch class and future method is one option apart from process builder.

If anyone has worked on similar requirement, your suggestion will surely help.

Comment: How often is this operation going to take place? Is there significant data volume in the 30 child objects?

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be a real update? Can't you just make bunch of formula fields on these child objects that reference data from parent? Why you've discounted straight away a trigger/process builder, you're sure you can hit 10K rows updated in single transaction limit?

Comment: @David Reed Just to ellborate main motive here is to keep all the child objects in sync with parent. Now suppose anyone changes the account owner then all the child objects irrespective of custom or standard relationship must have the same owner. About the volume it depends it's not fixed as there are many objects.

Comment: @eyescream, Just mentioned above the main agenda is to keep the ownership of record in sync. So there will a need to update. But this is sure any child object won't have more than 10k rows.